# " Syntax error: "(" unexpected " with table

Tags: shell

I have done few month ago a Linux script that announce on my server a reboot message with a timer. Since I have done some changes on my Linux, I have this error (launchSave.sh) `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`
for this line `TIMER=("30" "20" "5" "2" "1" "1" "1")`

The two modifications I have done on my Linux is using dash rather than bash (I changed it back to try) and using kexec for warm reboots (with this tutorial : https://wiki.debian.org/BootProcessSpeedup#Using_readahead_to_load_files_from_disk). I don't know if it's the reason but I suspect it. Like you can see I'm not an expert of Linux and script.

I have test `declare -a TIMER=` and `TIMER("30" "20" "5" "2" "1" "1" "1")` but always a "(" or ")" syntax 
 error.

**EDIT**

```
#! /bin/bash
TIMER=("30" "20" "5" "2" "1" "1" "1") ## Time between each annoucer
TOTAL_TIME="60" ## Total time variable of the timer to be subtracted
BUNGEECORD="bungeecord"
TODAY=`date +"%d%b%Y"`

mkdir /save/logs/${TODAY}
exec > /save/logs/${TODAY}/stop-log.txt ## Log file 

screen -x ${BUNGEECORD} -X stuff 'maintenance\n' ## Starting maintenance mode
screen -x ${BUNGEECORD} -X stuff 'alert &cVous pourrez vous reconnecter dans 5 minutes environ !\n'

## Loop to advert player from restarting
for time in ${TIMER[@]}
do

    screen -x ${BUNGEECORD} -X stuff 'alert &cRedémarrage automatique journalier dans &4'$TOTAL_TIME' &csecondes.\n'
    TOTAL_TIME=$(($TOTAL_TIME-$time))
    sleep $time

done

cd /home || exit

## Loop to stop every single server of the list above
for server in *
do

    ## Disociate BungeeCord to other server.
    if [ ! $server = ${BUNGEECORD} ]; then

        echo "Shutting down : $server"

        screen -x $server -X stuff "stop\n" ## run stop command in server screen

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "$server successfully shutting down"
        else
            echo "Error found during shutting down : $server"
        fi

    else 
        echo "Shutting down : ${BUNGEECORD}"

        screen -x ${BUNGEECORD} -X stuff "end\n" ## run stop command in server screen

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "${BUNGEECORD} successfully shutting down"
        else
            echo "Error found during shutting down : ${BUNGEECORD}"
        fi
    fi

done

sh sauvegarde.sh ## Launch save script

exit
```

B.

Comment: The array assignment is a "bash" feature. You script must be executed with '#! /bin/bash' or equivalent.

Comment: Also, considering sharing small script that demonstrate the problem, and allows replication. Hard to help you otherwise

Comment: I add all my script, and I already use '#! /bin/bash' :/ . I launch the script with : sh script.sh

Comment: @BoBsmil3Y : You launch it in the wrong way. If you run a script by `sh....`, it will be run by sh. If you would run it by, say, `perl .....`, it would be run by Perl. If you want to do it by bash, run it by `bash script.sh`. Alternatively, do a `chmod +x script.sh` and run it simply by `script.sh`. Your `#!` line will then ensure that bash is used.

Comment: Thanks ! For me, 'sh' was the standard launch command for bash.

Comment: When you launch with 'sh ...', it will start with '/bin/sh'. When bash starts as '*/sh', it will disable many non-Posix features. Try launching with './script.sh' ,or 'bash ./script.sh' or equivalent.

Comment: @user1934428: Consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You launch it in the wrong way. If you run a script by `sh ....`, it will be run by sh. What `sh` actually is, depends on the platform. It sometimes is symlinked either bash or zsh, but even then, those shells "know" that they are started by a different name and behave differently.

If you want a script being executed by bash, either run it by `bash script.sh` or, alternatively, do a `chmod +x script.sh` and run it simply by `./script.sh`. In the latter case, your #! line will then ensure that bash is used.

Comment: And in fact being able to run it as `script.sh` (or `./script.sh` if it's in the current directory -- `.` shouldn't be in your `$PATH` -- but I digress) is the whole point of the `#!/bin/bash` line.

Comment: I absolutely appreciate this disgress! I updated my answer accordingly.